# M.2 SSD doesn't show up in BIOS and Windows installer

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios

I am building a brand new PC with motherboard [Asus PRIME B250M-A](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/PRIME-B250M-A/) and a 250GB WD BLUE M2 2280 SSD drive.

The M.2 drive doesn't show up in BIOS. After a few attempts, disabling the CMS brings the M.2 entry in the BIOS, but the value is N/A. I changed the M.2 mode from AUTO to PCI-E and at the bootstrap I get a message that says a SATA device is connected to the M.2 port and to switch to SATA mode in the BIOS. I did that, and the N/A is always there.

Windows 10 installer doesn't show the drive either.

Comment: Did you format the drive? Does a tool that can format the drive see it?

Comment: The system is brand new, I can only attach to this brand new motherboard and there isn't any utilities in the bios to format it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That SSD is indeed SATA (not PCIe / NVMe).

Check that it's properly seated. Once you have it detected, it will likely show up as one of the SATA devices (not an M.2 device). From the manual:

> When M.2 Socket is set to SATA mode, SATA port 1 is disabled

Additionally, I noticed in your motherboard's manual, that it has *two* M.2 ports:

- `M.2_1` supports both SATA & PCIe 3.0 x4
- `M.2_2` supports only PCIe 3.0 x4

Make sure that you have the SSD in the correct port (labelled `M.2_1`).

Also, make sure that you don't have another disk connected to the `SATA6G_1` port (top).

---

Please just go through the motions to be 100% sure (even if you think you tried it).

1. Power off
2. Install SSD into `M.2_1`
3. Disconnect any drive / cable from `SATA6G_1`
4. Enter the BIOS and set `M.2_1` to SATA mode
5. Save configuration and reboot
6. Check devices found by BIOS again

Comment: I tried all 2 slots, same results. Now it's connect to the slot 1. I did disable the sata port 1 from the bios. N/A is always showed.

Comment: Please see the last part of my updated answer.

Comment: There are no cable on the G_1. The only drive is M2 one, but I get it!!! I reenable the G_1 Port from the Bios and now windows detect it corretcly! Shame on me. Maybe disable the Sata Port 1 by hand is not the proper way to do